# Declension of “drittgrößte” in “die drittgrößte Stadt”

Tags: numbers, adjective-ending

I am curious what kind of grammar law fits the adjective conjugation for *drittgrößt**e***. Is it a strong or weak adjective conjugation?
What confuses me is that, in my grammar book, it is mentioned that after numbers there is a strong adjective conjugation while in this case, *Stadt* is female and there is also a *die*.

> München ist die drittgrößte Stadt Deutschlands.

Comment: What would you expect? Furthermore there is no number in this sentence...

Comment: Since there could only be *one* "drittgrösste" there is always a definite article or adjective in singular connected with it, and therefore you don't have to think about any strong conjugation of the word, it would always be weak

Answer (score 5):

*Dritt-* isn't a number but a prefix for the superlative of *groß*. That's the same as in English, e.g. in *second largest* second isn't a number (a count) but a position on a chart.

An example with a number:

> Drei groß**e** Städte in Deutschland sind Berlin, Hamburg und München.

You can see it's strong flexion because the plural is not built with -en.

An example with a number and superlative:

> Die drei größt**en** Städte in Deutschland sind Berlin, Hamburg und München.

See how the flexion gets weak because of the (required) article in front.